# Representations of the formulas with the elements of the linear representations of $GF(2^2)$

Tags: finite-fields

The problem statement is as below.

Represent the following formulas with the elements which are of the linear representations of $GF(2^2)$  where the root $\alpha$ satisfies $x^2+x+1=0$ .

$(1)$ $\alpha^4$

$(2)$ $\alpha^2-(\alpha-1)$

$(3)$ $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^4}$

I have the following formula but I don't know how should I use it.

$GF(2^2)=\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha+1\}$     $,(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)$

Can someone let me know the solutions or some website that explain about the solutions?

Comment: Remember GF(2^2) has characteristic 2, so squaring is easy and minus signs are plus signs.

Comment: I see.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do one example, that isn't on your list, and then that should show you what is meant. I choose $\alpha^2+1$.

Now the elements of the field are $0,1,\alpha,\alpha+1$, so this is equal to one of those four elements. We have the equation $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$, so (as we are over a field of characteristic $2$) $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$.

Then $\alpha^2+1=(\alpha+1)+1=\alpha$.

Comment: Can I write the formula to the middle of the formulas as  $\alpha^2=-(\alpha+1)=(\alpha+1)$ ?
And the answers for the problems are $\alpha,0,1$respectivelty?

Comment: You can put - signs anywhere you want because - and + are the same thing in this field. And yes, those are correct.

Comment: I see.I'm sorry to bother you again.At last problem ,I got $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha}$ in the processes and I normally calculated it as same as an elementary way like $\alpha^1\times\alpha^-1=\alpha^0=1$ .Is is correct to do that?I have no knowledge about a division of the GF.

Comment: As long as your element $x$ is non-zero, $x/x=1$ in any field. Finite fields do all of the things you expect them to do, including multiplicative inverses working correctly.

Comment: I see.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by hypothesis, $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$ and so $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$.
From here you can easily answer the questions.

First, $\alpha^4 = \alpha^2\alpha^2 = (\alpha+1)^2 = \alpha^2+1 = (\alpha+1)+1 = \alpha.$

Second, $\alpha^2 - (\alpha-1) = \alpha^2 - \alpha+1$. But $-1=+1$ in the coefficient field $GF(2)$, and so you get $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$.

Third, $\alpha/\alpha^4 = \alpha^{-3}$. But $\alpha^3=1$ since $\alpha$ is 3rd root of unity, and so $\alpha^{-3}=1$.

Comment: Mistake in the first: $(\alpha+1)^2=\alpha^2+1$ not $\alpha+1$, as you see in the third.